Analysis of Progressive Series Modulation Circuit with Six Transistors and Cascaded Diodes

How Does the Progressive Series Modulation Circuit with Six Transistors Work?

I am analyzing the progressive series modulation circuit

Six transistors, Divided into distinct stages:

Q1 and Q2 (TIP47):  Modulator Stage

Q3 and Q4 (2N6254): Operate in Parallel

Q5 (2N6254): Connecting two Stages

Q6 and Q7 (2N6340): Modulated Final Power Amplifier Stage

Diodes:

IN3070 and IN914(3): Connected after the audio input

D1 (IN4005): Connect through DC volatage 71-volts



My Objectives:

Understand how the circuit works, particularly the roles of Q5, Q6, and Q7 in the final power amplifier stage.
Determine the Q-points for all transistors and their influence on the circuit operation.
Analyze the voltage gain, input impedance, and β (beta) for each transistor stage.
Explain the role of cascaded diodes (IN3070 and IN914) in the modulation process and their effect on voltage levels.
Calculate the voltage drop across each diode, including D1 (IN4005), and its impact on circuit performance.
Evaluate how Q6 and Q7 eliminate the need for a modulation transformer in this design.


Specific Cases to Explore:

Case 1: When Q1 (TIP47) turns ON at a specific voltage, how does it affect Q2 and the subsequent transistors (Q3–Q7)? How it will turn onn?
Case 2: When Q2 (TIP47) turns ON, what conditions lead to this? How do other transistors (Q1, Q3–Q7) respond, and how does it affect the modulation process?
Case 3: If Q3 and Q4 (2N6254) are ON, how does their parallel configuration handle higher power modulation, and what is their impact on Q5 and How the Q (3-4) will turn onn?
Case 4: If Q5 (2N6254) turns ON, what is its role in bridging the modulator and final RF stage? How does it affect Q6 and Q7 and How Q5 will turn on?
Case 5: When Q6 (2N6340) is ON, what conditions enable it to work with Q7 to amplify the modulated RF signal? and How it will turn onn?
Case 6: If Q7 (2N6340) is ON, how does it drive the RF output to the antenna, and what are the conditions for efficient operation? and How it will turn onn?


How Each Transistor Turns ON & OFF:

Goals:

Investigate why transistors (Q5, Q6, and Q7) were chosen to eliminate the modulation transformer and how this impacts circuit design.
Compare theoretical calculations (Q-points, gain, impedance, diode voltage drops) with practical measurements for validation.


For Text or Information from the Source:
The explanation of the progressive series modulation circuit with six transistors is adapted from Shoenbeck, Robert J. Electronics Communication Modulation and Transmission, 2nd ed., Archive.org, [https://archive.org/details/electroniccommun00robe]
Image Sources & Attribution:

Circuit Image: Adapted from Shoenbeck, Robert J. Electronics Communication Modulation and Transmission, 2nd ed., Archive.org, https://archive.org/details/electroniccommun00robe, p. 49.
Theory Image: Adapted from Shoenbeck, Robert J. Electronics Communication Modulation and Transmission, 2nd ed., Archive.org, https://archive.org/details/electroniccommun00robe, p. 48.





you will learn more by reading all the back issues of Electronic Design magazine from the 70's and just read the descriptions of submitted on 1 page designs. That's how I did it with the basic theory from Wiki's Applications. I gave you. It gives a part by part description from the author. This book only does partly.  But you ask too many questions for this site and too little effort on learning the theory, but excellent format with GPT help. I might have some better teaching links in my profile

Theory is a prerequisite then you will be able to analyze simple case 1 to infinity easier.  This is called a "discrete" Class C amplifier where the top "tranny" conducts alone and then the bottom of the pair in both cases 3-4,6-7 so they do not conduct at the same time and draw simultaneous power thus more efficient but need filters to remove harmonics.  So do not continue posting so many questions. Learn then ask a specific one you cannot find the answer to. Avoid this "spoon-feeding for infants to learn better with a learning curve though when you are ready.

Theory, then example circuits with increasing complexity. You are skipping the didactic learning steps.
